Went to switch leach field but don’t see switch
Bought my house in February. Knew it had some sort of way to “alternate” the septic between two leach fields. Finally got around to opening up what I assume is the correct lid (there are two lids on my septic tank and this one is distinctly further from the house than the other one) and do not see any obvious way to switch things. Just standing water and the outlet filter. I am assuming at this point that something is wrong and that the switch is under that murky water somewhere so I just need to have someone out to look at it - wanted to see if anyone here had any thoughts though. Thanks everyone.



what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

What do you mean by "switch"? If there is any option, it will be controlled by valves, not switches. I don't rock septic systems, but I'm not sure why you believe there is more than one leach field.

we first have to ask the question online...to understand leachfield and switching leach fields    I suppose a leachfield is where the tank empties?
